# Show total occurrence grouped and as a total in Kusto

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm quite new to Kusto and I'm trying to visualize something in an Azure Log Analytics workbook.
I'm searching for occurrences of requests, translate IDs to human readable names using a custom function and group them by day.
**I can't find a way to also show the total occurrences (sum of all groups) only as a metric and not changing the chart.**

My query looks like this:

```
    requests
    | where operation_Name == "Create History"
    | where customDimensions.SystemStatus == "Production"
    | extend systemid = tostring(customDimensions.SystemId)
    | extend system = tostring(system_lookup()[systemid])
    | summarize Services_Done = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d), system
```

Resulting in a time series bar chart like this:
[image]

Chart settings:
[image]

Comment: Could you try adding `union` at the end of the code in this way `union (
              summarize total = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d)
)`. @trial_and_error

Comment: @Jahnavi `| union(summarize Services_Done = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d), system)`gives me Query could not be parsed at 'summarize' on line [30,9]
Token: 'summarize' Line: 30 Postion: 9

Answer (score 0):

> **I can't find a way to also show the total occurrences (sum of all groups) only as a metric and not changing the chart.**

If you do not want to change chart and get sum of all services then use below query:

```
let res=requests 
| extend ProcessId = tostring(customDimensions.ProcessId)
| extend system = tostring(ProcessId)
| summarize Services_Done = count() by bin(timestamp, 1d), system
| extend new_column = 0
| sort by new_column asc
| extend rn=row_number();
let res2=res
| summarize Total_Services_Done = sum(Services_Done) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| extend new_column = 0
| sort by new_column asc
| extend rn=row_number();
res
| join kind=fullouter res2 on rn
| project-away new_column, rn,rn1,new_column1,timestamp1
| render barchart with (kind=stacked)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is giving me the exact same output as my original query.

Comment: It didn't give me, as you can clearly see in screen shots, have you tried the same?